# Align subfigures vertically

Tags: subfloats

It is easy using `subfigure` environment to place some figures side by side. How could we do it one on the top of the other one without messing with the alignment? Using linebreak (`\\`) instead of `\;` for instance seems not to derive the desired result.

Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chemfig}

% Title Page
\title{a}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
                \centering
                \chemfig{C(=[:0]O)(=[:180]O)}\;
                \chemfig{H-[::37.775,2]O-[::-75.55,2]H}\;
                \caption{Chemical Database}
                \label{fig:database}
        \end{subfigure}\newline
        %~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc. 
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \chemfig{C(-[:90]H)(-[:270]H)(=[:0]C(=[:0]C(-[:90]H)(-[:270]H)))}
                \caption{Query formula}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Query}\label{fig:query}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The desired result would be to have the first pair of formulas above the other while both figures are aligned to the center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say that the MWE doesn't give the desired formatting but you do not say what layout you want.

You have one full width figure and one 30%-width figure. It might have been simpler to have them both full width but assuming that you want them that size, but want the smaller one centred, then perhaps:

```
\begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
                \centering
                \chemfig{C(=[:0]O)(=[:180]O)}\;
                \chemfig{H-[::37.775,2]O-[::-75.55,2]H}\;
                \caption{Chemical Database}
                \label{fig:database}
        \end{subfigure}\\[10em]
        %~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad etc. 
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \chemfig{C(-[:90]H)(-[:270]H)(=[:0]C(=[:0]C(-[:90]H)(-[:270]H)))}
                \caption{Query formula}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Query}\label{fig:query}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a bad question. Your answer helped find the issue in my question and solve my problem.

Centering at the beginning seems to help. Removing the the weird 30%-width and converting it to 100% also resolves the issue.

Thanks a lot!